# How can I search for a phrase containing a space?

Tags: foursquare

When I try and search (using the default intent variable) for say 'shoe store' in my local geo area, it does not return expected results. How can I join words as one phrase in a Foursquare search API so that it would treat 'shoe store' as one search term not separate words?

I tried `%20`, `'-'`,`'+'` but no success.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following url:

`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?query=shoe+store&ll=40.7,-74&oauth_token=(MY_TOKEN)&v=20150721`

It return expected results. Please try it.